# 'with open' creates a file in the wrong directory

Tags: python, directory

I have a problem with the 'with open' function, because it creates a file in the wrong directory, for example, if I have this, (directory1/directory2/pythonfile.py) instead of creating a file in directory 2, it creates it in directory1, how can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your code (including how you're invoking it)?

Comment: The problem isn't `open`, but the combination of your current working directory (which is *not* `directory2`) and  the relative path you pass to `open` as an argument.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()) #current working directory  
os.chdir(path) #provide path where you want to create file--  /directory2  
#now use open to create your file
```

Comment: I would provide the full path to `open` instead. Changing the global state of the program isn't the best of ideas and not necessary.